# Symfony2, Unable to generate url on custom error page

Tags: symfony, twig

When I try to generate a route with twig in a custom error page :

```
{# app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig #}
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}
```

With a simple layout like this :

```
{# app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}
<a href="{{ path('index') }}">Index</a>
```

I get this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does not exist.") in ::layout.html.twig

If I try without extend the layout, that work :

```
{# app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig #}
<a href="{{ path('index') }}">Index</a>
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: The why is in the error message. Maybe you can find in the trace in exactly which line the error happened. You should check the layout file once again... or post the whole content. And should look out for [`is_granted` calls too](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#avoiding-exceptions-when-using-security-functions-in-error-templates) if you are using older version of symfony.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: use `/` instead of `{{ path('index') }}`.